# Java setImageResource

Tags: java, android

I have a little card game. In an ArrayList I add the 52 cards:

```
ArrayList<String> liste = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and fill it with this:

```
for (int n=1; n<14; n++) {
    liste.add("d" +n); //diamonds
    liste.add("c" +n); //clubs
    liste.add("s" +n); //spades
    liste.add("h" +n); //hearts
}
```

To draw a card I use this code:

```
private void drawCard() {
    if (liste.size()!=0) {
        Collections.shuffle(liste);
        kort.setText("" + liste.get(0));
        int i = liste.size();
        cardsLeft.setText("" + (i - 1));
        cardImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.XXX);
        liste.remove(0);
    }
    else kort.setText("No more cards in deck");
}
```

In my drawable folder I have 52 pictures of cards with the same name as the names in the ArrayList.
When the program draw eg. d2 i need to set the ImageView cardImage to image d2 from the drawable folder as well:

```
cardImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.d2);
```

Need help to how I change the imageview to match the drawn card

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
public static int getDrawableId(Context ctx, String name) {
   return ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());
}

cardImage.setImageResource(getDrawableId(YourActivity.this, "d2"));
```

Comment: Sorry for asking but how does this work? If the game draws d2 (Diamonds  of 2) the TextView will be updated with a simple code and show d2 on the screen. How do I update the  ImageView with image R.drawable.d2 ? Do I have to make a code for each single image? Something to replace: cardImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.liste.get(0));

Comment: Resources.getIdentifier(String name, String type) returns to you the identifier of the resource with a given name of a given type.
So, getIdentifier("d2", "drawable") returns R.drawable.d2

Or, getIdentifier("card_layout", "layout") returns R.layout.card_layout.

Resource identifiers are integers and you pass them where they needed such as to setImageResource()

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin Your example call to `getDrawableId()` misses the context parameter.